# failed to decode, caught ReaderException 'Could not find three finder patterns'

Tags: ios, barcode, qr-code, zxing

i have dwonloaded the zxing sdk.
in that their was an sample code called scantest which only scan qr code not barcode.

while reading barcode i am getting **failed to decode, caught ReaderException 'Could not find three finder patterns'** error
i want to make an app for both qr as well as for barcoder reading and give the output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building the code out of svn or the git mirror? The most recent code for ScanTest should run all the decoders, not just the QR decoder.